# Light bounding geometry for deferred rendering

Tags: lighting, deferred-rendering

What is the best bounding geometry to use in a deferred renderer for each one of the following light types?

- Sphere area light (obviously a sphere)
- Disk area light (obviously a cone)
- Rectangular area light (a frustum?)
- Tube area light (a frustum as well?)

And how can I create those geometries? For the sphere and the disk it's quite simple given the attenuation radius and the attenuation angle, but for the other ones?